# PHP not working correctly after call by jQuery 2nd time

Tags: jquery

Here is my jQuery code to call twitter.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#play").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'twitter.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: "user=<?php echo $user; ?>",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#first').hide();
                    $("#wait").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                    $('#result').html(data).delay(2500).fadeIn();
                    $("#again").hide().delay(2500).fadeIn();
                }
            });
        });
        $("#playagain").click(function(){
            $('#result').show().delay(300).fadeOut();
            $("#again").show().delay(300).fadeOut();
            $("#first").hide().delay(700).fadeIn();
        });
   });
</script>
```

And this is PHP to random number to image

```
        $randnum = rand(0,99);
        $photoz = "pic/bg".rand(1,7).".png";
        //$phoneim = $pic;  

        $file[0] = "im_{$user}.jpg";

        if (file_exists($file[0])) { 
    unlink("$file[0]");
    }           

        //GD ใส่ข้อความลงในภาพ
        $font_size = 100;
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($photoz);
        $destWidth = imagesx($im); 
        $font = realpath('font.ttf');
        $imessage = $horonum[$randnum];
        $color = ImageColorAllocate($im, 113, 193, 26);
        $text_y = 333;
    $text_bbox = ImageTTFBBox($font_size, 0, $font, $imessage);
    $image_centerx = ($destWidth / 2)-7;
    $text_x = $image_centerx - round(($text_bbox[4]/2));

        ImageftText($im, $font_size, 0, $text_x, $text_y, $color, $font, $imessage);
        imagejpeg($im,"im_{$user}.jpg");
        imagedestroy($im);
        //*************
```

The 1st time jQuery call PHP everything work fine
but after repeat click play button the random number still the same as the 1st time
how to fix this?

Comment: In which browser did you try this?

Comment: have you thought about the browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a cache issue. Try adding `cache: false`, to your ajax options.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

cache
Boolean
Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.